# Profiling Java mongodb query with JProfiler, what is the difference between "Retrieve Data" and "Query"

Tags: java, mongodb, profiling, jprofiler

I am profiling some mongodb queries that are executed by our java app. In the profiler, there seems to be two sets of logged queries, one for "Retrieve Data" and one for "Query find"

Does anyone know the difference between the blocks shown in the pic here?

Thanks!

[image: profiling image]

Answer (score 1):

"Query" shows the calls to find while "retrieve data" is the time that is spent by MongoDB driver going back to the database when you use the iterator that is returned by a find call.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Ingo. So in terms of performance tuning, there isnt much that can be done for "Query" duration, correct? And any optimization will make the "Find" call faster, but not reduce the Retrieve data step. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not an expert in MongoDB tuning, so I could not say. The two different payload types have been introduced to make it clear where the time is being spent, whether in the initial query or the subsequent retrieval of the results.